# Vagrant with xdebug can't connect to host

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

My vagrant setup for the network is `config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.56.101"`. If I'm accessing a php page with `echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` I got `192.168.56.1` as result. The problem now is that I can't ping `192.168.56.1`, so also the config for Xdebug with `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1` will fail, because Xdebug tries to connect to `192.168.56.1`. If I use my normal ip address with `xdebug.remote_host=X.X.X.X` everything works fine, but I want to use `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1`. What can I do that it will work?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and then started up a Virtualbox manually and realized that I hadn't started a virtualbox since updating and the firewall had to updated.  Once I restarted virtualbox I could ping 192.168.56.1 and not have to rely on a hard coded ip address.  So, my guess, is that you probably have firewall issues.